# Angular 2 and Webpack - url() in SASS file cannot resolve even with resolve-url-loader

Tags: angularjs, sass, webpack

I started my Angular 2 Webpack project from [this official guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html).

I went ahead and ran `npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader resolve-url-loader`. That went well.

My component is sitting at `root/src/app/mycomponent/mycomponent.ts`, and I'm referencing my scss in the heading this way:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './mycomponent.html',
    styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.scss']
})
```

The scss file is at `root/src/app/mycomponent/mycomponent.scss` and I have the following SASS in there:

```
p{
    color: blue;
    background-image: url('./background.jpg');
}
```

That image is sitting at `root/src/app/mycomponent/background.jpg`.

In `webpack.common.js` I have the following rule for .scss files:

```
{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   exclude: 'node_modules',
   loaders:  ['style-loader','css-loader','resolve-url-loader','sass-loader?sourceMap']
}
```

as recommended by [resolve-url-loader documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader).

I keep on getting this error:

ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?sourceMap!./src/app/mycomponent/mycomponent.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './background.jpg'

I even tried `loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap!resolve-url-loader'})` and I'm still getting the same error.

For the life of me, I can't figure out what I did wrong. I was under the impression that resolve-url-loader will let me put a location in SASS url() **relative to the .scss file it's declared in!** That background.jpg sits in the same folder as my .scss file, so I think I referenced the path correctly.

I searched SO and the web and nobody seems to have the right solution. Is there any other code I need to show? Please help! And please, I don't want to import or require image files from .ts.

---

**Update**

It turns out that I misspelled the name of the image's file name. Now, I don't get that "module not found" error.

**HOWEVER** I now get the error in the browser's console output: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings. This is with the configuration

```
loaders: ['style-loader','css-loader','resolve-url-loader','sass-loader?sourceMap']
```

Still stuck.

Comment: Maybe this can help you .see https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader/issues/32

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message, Angular is expecting assets to be strings while resolving the code. Thus in this situation, we need another loader here:

```
npm install --save-dev css-to-string-loader
```

Then in your webpack config file:

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  loaders: ['css-to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
},
```

It should be good to go now.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get passed this issue by using 'exports-loader' instead of 'style-loader'

eg:
`'exports-loader?module.exports.toString()'`